# Unable to locate element when element is still present

Tags: selenium

> Driver is unable to find element on the page even when its present 
>   . Basically Im just trying that when a popup (ad popup which we see in many website) is present it should get clicked. Below is the code  :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\SeleniumDriver\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        //driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.sportskeeda.com/wwe");
        //WebElement popup=driver.findElement(By.className("bullbg"));
        WebElement popup=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Close')]"));


        if (popup.isDisplayed())
        {

            System.out.println("True");
        }
        else 
        {

            System.out.println("False");
        }
```

ERROR

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   Unable to locate element: //div[contains(text(),'Close')]

[Please click here to check there is a popup which gets display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGAiY.jpg)

Comment: Why do you think it should be there? I've just checked that url and it did not show up any pop up ads.

Comment: The pop up does show up sometimes so need to check if it does or not
if it does click on close or not then start with other step in the script.

Comment: So please update your question so that it represents the actual issue. Because in your current question it is not mentioned that it might appear or not.

Comment: ya please check the link image its shows a pop up

Answer (score 0):

Try scrolling to the element first, something might be in the way

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("id"));

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Instead:

Boolean popup=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Close')]")).isDisplayed();

if (popup == true)
        {

```
        System.out.println("True");
    }
    else 
    {

        System.out.println("False");
    }
```

Comment: I gave a try with Boolean it did not worked then I try 2 way both are unable to find the image or any element of the image.